# How to solve java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError after CXF 3.5.3 upgrade (Java Application - JRE 8)?

Tags: version, cxf, jax-ws, conflict

Since upgrading the cxf Version used to build our Java Application from 2.7.18 to 3.5.3 we encounter the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class org.apache.cxf.jaxws.WrapperClassGenerator has interface org.apache.cxf.common.util.ASMHelper as super class
```

The super class of WrapperClassGenerator has indeed changed between older versions of cxf and version 3.5.x. but "mvn dependency:tree-Dverbose" shows only the correct CXF 3.5.3 dependencies are included in the build. Calling org.apache.cxf.version.Version.getCompleteVersionString() at runtime also shows correct version 3.5.3.

So i have no idea where that version conflict is coming from. Can it have something to do with jax-ws version supplied by the java runtime? We use Java 1.8.0_202-b08 JRE at runtime. The cxf website claims cxf 3.5.3 works with Java8. I also tried using the java endorsed mechanism to drop newer version of Jax-ws and Jaxb jars into java (and the even newer Jakarta Jars which i doubt it will even pick up...). No effect at all.

Currently running out of ideas. Has anyone had similar problems or an idea how to debug this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. I just found out our application has a folder from where it supplies some additional jar files of its own during runtime. I found some ancient cxf jar files there that i somehow managed to overlook for weeks now. Dropped the correct cxf and spring jar files into that folder instead of the old ones and everything works fine now.